# Automatically colour the absolute complete reference cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 . Sheet 2 A2 has the name of cities. I have used absolute reference (i.e. =) to link the name of cities from sheet 2 A2 to sheet 1 A1.

Now what I am trying to do is whenever I link cities' names from Sheet 2 A2 to Sheet 1 A1, I want the linked cities cell to automatically turn into red background colour. This way I can know which city's name from sheet 2 A2 has been linked to Sheet 1 A1.

Can anyone please help me on this. This would really save a lot of time in my work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking questions in the Help Center. StackOverflow is not a tutorial or code-writing service. It's a Q&A site to ask specifically targeted questions about a problem encountered while writing code. You at least have to show us the code you've tried and explain how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA. Use conditional formatting:

- Highlight your list of countries in `Sheet2`
- From menu: Conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...
- Type this formula in: **=$A2:$A10=Sheet1!$A$1**
- Set the format e.g. bold, red background...

Clearly adjust the formula to match your cell references.

Comment: Thank you so much...I wanna be very good at excel. I know the basics. Can you tell me where do i get started to learn the kind of skills you just answered. :-)

Comment: I would get an excel reference book, read every chapter, and get an appreciation of what can be done with Excel. Then it's all about practice. For example, in this case you need to know about `array formulas` to see that it is a good fit in your situation. In my view the key is knowing what tools you can use as that leads you to better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Macro 4.0 function to return the formula in the cell and look in the formula to see if **Sheet1!** exists.  No VBA required.

- Select cell A1 on Sheet2.
- create a named range called **IsReference**:  `=GET.CELL(41,Sheet2!A1)`
  Note that A1 is a relative reference (no $ in it).
- Create a conditional format:
  Use a formula to determine which cell to format:  `=IFERROR(FIND("Sheet1!",IsReference),0)<>0`

NB - the 41 in the formula:
41  Returns the formula in the active cell without translating it (useful for international macro sheets).

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html